# showing Exception when passing id in Intent

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

i am facing a problem when i am passing id of Categories in intent like this

```
 @Override
    public void onCategoryListInteraction(TopCategory item) {
        Intent newIntent = new Intent(this, Common_Provider_Activity.class);
        newIntent.putExtra("id", item.getId());
        startActivity(newIntent);
    }
```

and in the second activity where i have to use this id it is showing me the error  here...

```
 public Integer id;
 id = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");
        RetrofitUtil.createProviderAPI().getProviderCategories(id , "category_providers").enqueue(providerCatList(this));
```

i am not understanding how to solve this question

Comment: what Exception? you're not showing nearly enough information. Also show more of your code, is that last bit in the class, in a method?

Comment: Post the error log.

Comment: Is TopCategory a Parcelable or Serializable object?
And the log would be nice.

Comment: Use getIntent().getIntExtra("id", here_a_default_int_value);

Comment: error resolved Thanks All